# Tensorflow / mobilenet training / ValueError: Unsupported input_reader_config

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror

I'm trying to traing Mobilenet to recognize custom objects.

I'm following this guide:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9

and using a checkpoint and pipeline.config from here:
[ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09.tar.gz)

**The Problem**

When I start traing with the following command:

```
python object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=C:\t\models\pipeline.config \
--model_dir=C:\t\models\ \
--num_train_steps=50000 \
--alsologtostderr
```

I get the following:

```
C:\tensorflow\models-master\research>path=C:\t\models\pipeline.config \     --model_dir=C:\t\models\ \     --num_train_steps=50000 \     --alsologtostderr
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x0000013B6CD26C80>) includes params argument, but params are not pa
ssed to Estimator.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 101, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 97, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 447, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 531, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 681, in run_local
    eval_result, export_results = evaluator.evaluate_and_export()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 886, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 453, in evaluate
    input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1346, in _evaluate_build_graph
    model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.EVAL))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 985, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1074, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py", line 493, in _eval_input_fn
    transform_input_data_fn=transform_and_pad_input_data_fn)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 150, in build
    raise ValueError('Unsupported input_reader_config.')
ValueError: Unsupported input_reader_config.
```

A comment in "dataset_builder.py" says:

> Raises:
>       ValueError: On invalid input reader proto.
>       ValueError: If no input paths are specified.

**Question:**

Is it a problem with pipeline.config file?

Does it mean that "dataset_builder.py" can't read it?

**OR**

Shall I pass some additional input path as it stated in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, cause of the problem was I didn't prepare test data. There was a training data only. So I prepared a list of test images with related XML files and generated test TFrecord.

Then the error has gone.

P.S.
I had a lot of other errors later but it's another story :)